# Magento Customer Associated website

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

My installation of magento is set to share customer accounts global. So any customer can log in to any magento-website.
But I want them to be redirected to their "associated-website" after they loggged in.

I override the AccountController and override the Login-flow and let the _loginPostRedirect() function deal with the redirect. Their may be a better way to do this but it "works".

The problem is that they are not logged in after they've been redirected.
As far as I know it is some sort of anonymous user in the session that keeps track of what site your on. And it is also the place you will be logged in to after you've logged in.

I want to reset/update or do something to get magento to sign in the customer on their associated website insted.

I've also looked at the Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php and hardcoded the website_id on places I've thought were in charge of this without effect.

Any hint/answer is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem :).

[This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/48574/)
thread talks about it and mention an extension that solves the problem.

In case someone else is wondering.

/G

Comment: the link not work more, do you remember the title to search that?